# Like And Dislike Specific ID

Tags: react-native

I tried to make like and dislike button with only change specific ID, but the problem is making all the component to like all and dislike all instead here my code :

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, ScrollView, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import {  Card } from '@rneui/themed';
import {  Button } from '@rneui/base';
import VirtualData from '../API/VirtualData';

export default function CardBox() {
  const [likes, setLikes] = useState(0)
  const [dislikes, setDislikes] = useState(0)
  const [likeActive, setLikeActive] = useState(false)
  const [dislikeActive, setdisLikeActive] = useState(false)

  const DislikeAct = () =>{
    setdisLikeActive(!dislikeActive)
    setDislikes(dislikeActive ? dislikes - 1 : dislikes + 1)
  }
  const LikeAct = () =>{
    setLikeActive(!likeActive)
    setLikes(likeActive ? likes - 1 : likes + 1)
  }

  const handleAllLikes = () =>{
    if(dislikeActive){
      LikeAct();
      DislikeAct();
    }
    LikeAct();
  }
  const AdvLikes = (id) => {
    var data = VirtualData.filter((item)=> item.likesId === id).map((item)=>(item.likesId))
    if(data.toString()){
      if(dislikeActive){
        LikeAct();
        DislikeAct();
      }
      LikeAct();
    }

  }

  const HandleAllDislikes = () =>{
    if(likeActive){
      DislikeAct();
      LikeAct();
    }
    DislikeAct();
  }

  const ResetLike = () =>{
    setLikes(0)
    setDislikes(0)
    setLikeActive(false)
    setdisLikeActive(false)
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.AllBtn}>
            <Button onPress={()=> handleAllLikes()} containerStyle={styles.BtnContainer}>Like All</Button>
            <Button onPress={()=> ResetLike()} type='outline' containerStyle={styles.BtnContainer}>Reset</Button>
            <Button onPress={()=> HandleAllDislikes()} containerStyle={styles.BtnContainer} color='error'>Dislike All</Button>
        </View>
        <FlatList
        data={VirtualData}
        renderItem={({item})=>(
          <Card containerStyle={styles.cardStyle}>
            <Image style={styles.CardImg} source={{uri:item.uri}}/>
            <View style={styles.BtnStyle}>
                <Button containerStyle={styles.LikeTxt} size="md" type="outline"><Text>{likes}</Text></Button>
                <Button onPress={()=> AdvLikes(item.likesId)} containerStyle={styles.BtnContainer} size="md">Like</Button>
                <Button onPress={()=> HandleAllDislikes()} containerStyle={styles.BtnContainer} color='error' size="md">Dislike</Button>
            </View>
        </Card>
        )}
        keyExtractor={item => item.likesId}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width : '100%',
        marginTop: 55,
        marginBottom : 15,
        borderRadius : 15,
        backgroundColor : '#FFFFFF',
  },
  cardStyle:{
      borderRadius:15
  },
  CardImg:{
    width : '100%',
    height : 200,
    resizeMode: 'contain'
  },
  BtnStyle:{
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  BtnContainer:{
    padding:5,
    justifyContent:'center',
    borderRadius:15
  },
  LikeTxt:{
      padding:5,
      justifyContent:'flex-start'
  },
  AllBtn:{
      flexDirection:'row',
      justifyContent:'center'
  }
});
```

this page is exporting array called VirtualData.js

```
const VirtualData = [
    {
      "name": "Linkin Park",
      "song": "In the End",
      "uri": "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/32242596?s=460&u=1ea285743fc4b083f95d6ee0be2e7bb8dcfc676e&v=4",
      "likesId": "eVTXPUF4Oz4"
    },
    {
      "name": "Breaking Benjamin",
      "song": "Diary of Jane",
      "uri": "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/32242596?s=460&u=1ea285743fc4b083f95d6ee0be2e7bb8dcfc676e&v=4",
      "likesId": "DWaB4PXCwFU"
    },
    {
      "name": "Starset",
      "song": "My Demons",
      "uri": "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/32242596?s=460&u=1ea285743fc4b083f95d6ee0be2e7bb8dcfc676e&v=4",
      "likesId": "p-N_y1bZtRw"
    },
    {
      "name": "Thousand Foot Krutch",
      "song": "War of Change",
      "uri": "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/32242596?s=460&u=1ea285743fc4b083f95d6ee0be2e7bb8dcfc676e&v=4",
      "likesId": "HdnTSXUWd3E"
    }
  ]
export default VirtualData;
```

I tried to make like and dislike button with only change specific ID, but the problem is making all the component to like all and dislike all instead, please help me coders what am i doing wrong